# Getting Request Timed Out - ASIHTTPRequest - code provided

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest, cfnetwork

Most of the time I end up in `failMethod`, I get the message `Request timed out` and a whole lot of jargon in the error. Why is this? Is there a solution for it?

I am using `ASIHTTPRequest`

```
[self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
[[self networkQueue] setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(successMethod:)];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(failMethod:)];    
ASIHTTPRequest *r = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/wenb"]];
[r setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[[self networkQueue] addOperation:r];    
[[self networkQueue] go];
```

Answer (score 3):

`Request timed out` generally means what it says: that the server you're trying to get data from took too long to respond, and your request was terminated (I assume the URL you've posted isn't the URL you're trying to reach).

There are two solutions: preferably, figure out why your requests are taking so long to complete, because `ASIHTTPRequest` has a 10 second time out as default, which is quite long. The other, easier, option is to increase the timeout to, say, 30 seconds, which you can do like this:

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:30]
```

Perhaps try running your requests through something other than the phone to see how long they take, and to get more visibility on what the problem is.

Comment: Well, this is not the actual URL :). When i paste the URL in a browser window it gets displayed instantly (less than 1 second). Am i doing something wrong in my code ?

Comment: No, there's nothing that appears incorrect in the code you've posted. Try accessing the URL through mobile safari to narrow things down: if it loads in there, you know it's a problem with your app, and if it doesn't you know it's a problem with the network your device is on.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is depends on the **mobile carriers**. I got the same issue and I have tested on different carrier network using same application. It seems to me the network providers are using different type of connectivity (proxies). When you look at your phone logs, you can see same error from you mail client too.  The one solution is, use the simple `NSURLConnection` with `HTTP` methods.

Comment: I think ASIHTTPRequest is using streaming rather than HTTP POST/GET.